# How to use Ext.XTemplate directly on a panel on ExtJS 6/7

Tags: extjs

This doesn't show anything inside the panel body:

```
  {                     
    xtype: 'panel',                     
    title: 'Test',                     
    region: 'east',                     
    width: 400,                     
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<p>Hello world</p>'),                     
    split: true,                     
    collapsible: true                 
    }
```

The panel is correctly rendered, since I can put data inside the "html" property and it works.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by it shows nothing? Since you can see the html property, it means its showing that. Can you add fiddle with reproducible example or how it looks using a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide a `data` config to display the tpl. As per to [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-tpl), it works in conjunction with data. For the time being, the data can be an empty array.

Refer the below code or [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dtd)

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Test',
    region: 'east',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    data: [],
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<p>Hello world</p>'),
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}
```